# GitLab not accessible with enabled firewall (OS: Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: ubuntu, gitlab, firewall, system-administration, ufw

### Description

A few days ago i installed GitLab and it seemed to work just fine, but when i tried to connect today it printed an 502 error (to long time to load).

*!! As i stated above, it works Perfectly fine with disabled Firewall :)*

Code:

```
gitlab-ctl tail
```

Output:

```
2017-09-04_09:18:29.94177 2017/09/04 11:18:29 error: GET "/": badgateway: failed after 30s: dial tcp [::1]:8081: getsockopt: connection refused
2017-09-04_09:18:29.94187 git.myurl.com @ - - [2017-09-04 11:17:59.940389308 +0200 CEST] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 2925 "" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36" 30.001060
2017-09-04_09:18:30.27682 2017/09/04 11:18:30 Send static file "/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/public/favicon.ico" ("") for GET "/favicon.ico"
2017-09-04_09:18:30.27712 git.myurl.com @ - - [2017-09-04 11:18:30.276480568 +0200 CEST] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 5430 "https://git.myurl.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36" 0.000454
```

### Already Tried

After trying and researching i found out that it works perfectly fine with disabled firewall so i looked up the needed ports and allowed them via

```
ufw allow "rule"
```

This are my Open Ports now:

```
ufw status
```

Output:

```
Status: active
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
OpenSSH                    ALLOW       Anywhere                      
Apache Full                ALLOW       Anywhere                  
3306                       ALLOW       Anywhere                  
Dovecot IMAP               ALLOW       Anywhere                  
Postfix                    ALLOW       Anywhere                  
Postfix SMTPS              ALLOW       Anywhere                  
Postfix Submission         ALLOW       Anywhere                  
Dovecot Secure IMAP        ALLOW       Anywhere                  
8080                       ALLOW       Anywhere                  
9987/udp                   ALLOW       Anywhere                  
1194                       ALLOW       Anywhere                  
80                         ALLOW       Anywhere                  
443                        ALLOW       Anywhere                  
1194/udp                   ALLOW       Anywhere                  
8443                       ALLOW       Anywhere                  
122                        ALLOW       Anywhere                  
123/udp                    ALLOW       Anywhere                  
161/udp                    ALLOW       Anywhere                  
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere                  
8081                       ALLOW       Anywhere                  
OpenSSH (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
Apache Full (v6)           ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
3306 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
Dovecot IMAP (v6)          ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
Postfix (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
Postfix SMTPS (v6)         ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
Postfix Submission (v6)    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
Dovecot Secure IMAP (v6)   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
8080 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
9987/udp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
1194 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
80 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
443 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
1194/udp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
8443 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
122 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
123/udp (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
161/udp (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
22 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
8081 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

I tried a few things now, but i have no clue why it wont work.

```
gitlab-ctl reconfigure
```

works just fine (like 10 times already).

I also restarted the server several times (and i can connect to gitlab every time, but only with disabled ufw)

```
gitlab-ctl status
```

Output:

```
run: gitaly: (pid 1385) 2506s; run: log: (pid 1383) 2506s
run: gitlab-monitor: (pid 1403) 2506s; run: log: (pid 1401) 2506s
run: gitlab-workhorse: (pid 1386) 2506s; run: log: (pid 1384) 2506s
run: logrotate: (pid 1400) 2506s; run: log: (pid 1399) 2506s
run: node-exporter: (pid 1409) 2506s; run: log: (pid 1408) 2506s
run: postgres-exporter: (pid 1410) 2506s; run: log: (pid 1402) 2506s
run: postgresql: (pid 1391) 2506s; run: log: (pid 1389) 2506s
run: prometheus: (pid 1407) 2506s; run: log: (pid 1406) 2506s
run: redis: (pid 1387) 2506s; run: log: (pid 1382) 2506s
run: redis-exporter: (pid 1405) 2506s; run: log: (pid 1404) 2506s
run: sidekiq: (pid 1396) 2506s; run: log: (pid 1395) 2506s
run: unicorn: (pid 1390) 2506s; run: log: (pid 1388) 2506s
```

### My Configuration

Code:

```
grep "^[^#;]" /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb
```

Output:

```
external_url 'https://git.myurl.com'
unicorn['port'] = 8081
gitlab_git_http_server['auth_backend'] = "http://localhost:8081"
web_server['external_users'] = ['www-data']
nginx['enable'] = false
gitlab_rails['internal_api_url'] = 'https://git.myurl.com'
```

### Weird Behaviour of ufw

*Maybe Important, don't know*

When i installed openvpn i had to add stuff to /etc/ufw/before.rules

Code:

```
less /etc/ufw/before.rules
```

Output (only relevant Stuff):

```
# START OPENVPN RULES
# NAT table rule
*nat
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0] 
# Allow traffic from OpenVPN client to wlp11s0 (change to the interface 
you discovered!)
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/8 -o ens3 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# END OPENVPN RULES
```

When i do

```
ufw reload
```

Output:

```
ERROR: problem running ufw-init
Bad argument `*nat'
Error occurred at line: 21
Try `iptables-restore -h' or 'iptables-restore --help' for more 
information.

Problem running '/etc/ufw/before.rules'
```

But when i run

```
ufw enable
```

right after it, it works and Firewall is active after that

```
Command may disrupt existing ssh connections. Proceed with operation (y|n)? y
Firewall is active and enabled on system startup
```

As this is my First question ever asked on stackoverflow (yes i know how to google and never had to start a Thread myself ;) ) i hope i provided enough Info (if not just tell me) and somebody finds the time to help me,

thank you in advance,

*Paul*

*edit:* it works when i comment out the OpenVPN Rules in before.rules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ucommenting openvpn rules in before.rules solved the problem, i though want to know how to enable the masquerade without braking gitlab